# Javascript moving cursor on table that is editable move on save row

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, html-table

I have Javascript to where a cursor moves on up, down, enter on a table. It works but I want to move the cursor left and right on the same row. How can I do that?

I tried and it doesn't work:

```
else if (evt.keyCode == 39){
    event.preventDefault();
    var cellindex = $(this).index()
    var rowindex = $(this).parents('td').index() + 1
    $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
}
```

This is the working code for up, down, enter.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').keydown(function(evt){
        if(evt.keyCode == 40){
            event.preventDefault();
            var cellindex = $(this).index()
            var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() + 1
            $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
        }else if (evt.keyCode == 38){
                event.preventDefault();
            var cellindex = $(this).index()
            var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() - 1
            $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == 13){
                event.preventDefault();
            var cellindex = $(this).index()
            var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() + 1
            $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code, after the last `else if (evt.keyCode == 13){`:

```js
// other key handlers [...]
}
else if (evt.keyCode == 39){
    event.preventDefault();

    var rowindex =  $(this).parents('tr').index();
    var cellindex = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
}
else if (evt.keyCode == 37){
    event.preventDefault();

    var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index();
    var cellindex = $(this).index() - 1;
    $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
}
```

`evtKeyCode == 39` is for the right arrow being pressed, `evt.keyCode == 37` is for the left arrow.

Basically, all you had to do is flip around the row index and cell index from what you had previously.

[Here's a CodePen of it working](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/scKmw)

Comment: Question. This does work. But In my table I have some editable columns and some that are not and this stops at the ones that are not. Anything I Can do to skip over the ones that are not editable?